# How to Pass a value to input field through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

My Question :  A value which is passed by an id is showing in the input box. but i can not see that value in the html source code section.

This is my input field In which i am passing a value through a cookie.

```
<input type="text" id="city" class="i-p-c" value="" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Select City">
```

**What i am doing is:** I have a drop down of cities. when i click on the city. i am setting a cookie with the name of scity.

```
$("#cuto li").click(function () {
    autoValuenew = this.id; // console.log(autoValuenew);
    document.cookie = "scity=" + this.id + ";path=/;domain=" + cookieondomain;

   document.getElementById('city').value = this.id; 
   //Here is am pass a value to city 

return false;
});
```

After that ..
I can access the  value of city but i can not see that value in the html source code.

When i change my field type text to hidden type i can see the value in the htmlsource code.

I do not understand what is going here with these two types. or if i am doing something please tell where i am doing wrong.  or if there is another way to do this.

Comment: What do you mean by _can not see that value in the html element section_?

Comment: in my source code @H77

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31322704/why-does-jquery-val-only-change-value-attribute-for-hidden-input-fields

Comment: do you get any errors in console window?

Comment: No.. i did not get @M.Nabeel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
element.setAttribute('value', myValue);


I think you should not just change the value change it in by changing attribute value.
```

Answer (score 3):

Kindly look this code I hope it helps

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="city" class="i-p-c" value="" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Select City"/>
<ul id="cuto">
<li type="button" id="cuto">test</li>
</ul>
```

here is your JQuery

```
$("#cuto li").click(function () {
debugger;
    autoValuenew = this.id; // console.log(autoValuenew);
    $.cookie("scity", "test value"); // Setting cookie value
    //document.cookie = "scity=" + this.id + ";path=/;domain=" + cookieondomain;

   document.getElementById('city').value = this.id; 
   //Here is am pass a value to city 

return false;
});
```

Comment: Thank you @M.Nabeel

Comment: Happy to be help Vishal.
If it helps please marked it as answer :)

Comment: But what i needed is  @Pratheesh Answer